# How a fixed support which allows lateral contraction and expansion will look like?

Tags: classical-mechanics, structural-beam

I stumbled upon an exercise problem wherein it was asked to calculate the change in lateral dimensions of a bar fixed between two immovable supports, when temperature of the bar is increased by $\Delta T$ as shown in (A). It doesn't make sense to me how the bar will be able to laterally expand if it is fixed? IMO the lateral change in dimension should be zero at the ends and should increase as we approach the center of the bar.

[image]

I see a similar problem with case (B). When load is applied how the lateral dimensions can change if the bar is fixed at one end.

I asked a similar question in EngineeringSE community and was suggested by some members that the supports need not restrict lateral changes in dimensions. Even though the bar is "fixed" it can allow Lateral expansion and contraction.
**How such a support will look like? - which allows lateral expansion/ Contraction**

Someone suggested on the EngineeringSE that following could be a type of "fixed" support which permits lateral expansion and contraction:
[image]

**Any real life examples of such a support?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It doesn't make sense to me how the bar will be able to laterally
> expand if it is fixed?

The lateral change in Fig A due to thermal expansion is the poisson effect due to the compressive stress exerted by the constraints. In other words, axial compression of a bar not only causes shortening of the bar, but also elongation of the lateral dimensions. In this case the compressive stress is due to the thermal elongation of the bar that *would have occurred* if the constraints were not there. That elongation is the $dl$ shown in the following link:

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stress-restricting-thermal-expansion-d_1756.html

> I see a similar problem with case (B). When load is applied how the
> lateral dimensions can change if the bar is fixed at one end.

An axial tension load causes shortening of the lateral dimension, again due to the Poisson effect. Poisson's Ratio $\nu$ for a material relates the lateral strain to the longitudinal strain, according to $\nu=$ -lateral strain/longitudinal strain. Thus

$$\nu=\frac{-\Delta L_{Lat}/L_{Lat}}{\Delta L_{Lon}/L_{Lon}}$$

Note that $\nu$ is positive (+) if the bar is in tension and negative (-) if the bar is  in compression.

For case (B) think about a rubber band that you hold one end in one hand (the fixed support) and pull the rubber band with the other hand. When you stretch it you will see the rubber band get thinner.

> Any real life examples of such a support?

Most cantilever support examples that I'm aware of involve vertical loading. But you can try and google "tensile loads on cantilever supported beams" or the like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. I was actually refering to how the bar is able to expand laterally given that it is fixed at both ends and one end. I agree that we can calculate the lateral expansion using Poisson's ratio, but my question is how the bar is even able to expand laterally if its fixed. If I weld the bar at one or both ends, how will it be able to expand laterally. Only way it could expand laterally would be if there is some special kind of support which allows lateral expansion as well as keeps the bar in place. Was looking for such examples of supports.

Comment: @HarshitRajput Let's take this one step at a time. First, do you agree that if the restraints were not present in case A, that the bar would elongate due to thermal expansion?

Comment: Yes I do. Both lengthwise and lateral dimensions would've increased

Comment: @HarshitRajput OK. Now do you agree that in order to return the heated bar to its original length, without cooling it, you would need to apply a compressive stress which would further increase the lateral dimensions?

Comment: Yes I do. At the end, the total change in lateral dimension will be the sum of change in lateral dimension due to thermal effects and compressive load.

Comment: @HarshitRajput Good, then you just proved that the bar is under compression due to the fixed supports preventing the bar from elongating. That's the thermal stress due to heating.  The only thing is the static friction between the surfaces of the bar and the fixed supports may prevent lateral expansion at the ends of the bar,  i.e., the lateral expansion may not be uniform along the length. Kind of a "bulge" in the middle if you will.

Comment: Yes I was actually expecting a bulge. Oh yes bulge was the right word. So if the exercise problem is asking me to determine the lateral change in dimension, its assuming zero static friction.

Comment: @HarshitRajput Yes, at least that's how I see it. Otherwise it would seem like a very complicated deformation problem. You might want to Google up "Poisson effect on columns" or something like that, if you want to pursue it further. In any case, have I satisfactorily answered your question?

Comment: Yes sure! I'm satisfied with the answer

Comment: Refer to case A. Imagine that the bar is welded at the ends. Upon increasing the temperature, lateral expansion will be zero at the ends and will keep on increasing as we go away from ends and there may be a point after which the lateral expansion becomes constant along the length. Is this something we encounter in real life? That only near the ends lateral expansion varies (in a small portion of the bar) but away from the ends becomes uniform (uniform in a major portion of the bar). And due to this we can assume as a first approx. the lateral dim. to vary uniformly along the entire length?

Comment: @HarshitRajput  I'm sorry, but these are structural engineering questions that I'm not competent to answer. Moreover, such questions would be  more appropriate for an engineering stack exchange as opposed to the physics stack exchange.

Comment: Oh no problem at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are examples of this throughout the engineering world. They all involve building gaps into the supports to allow expansion and contraction. In the case of a simply-supported beam, this is simple: the next beam in the series is gapped by a fraction of an inch away from the previous beam. In the case of a cantilevered beam it could be accomplished by a sliding joint (a bar inside a close-fitting tube) connecting the free end of the beam with the next beam over.

These features are called *expansion joints*- try googling for examples and images.